# hive sql query to select var between values we get from another sub select query

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hql

I want to do this

```
select x,y,z from table1 where x between (select a from table2) and (select b from table2);
```

is this possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t1.x, t1.y, t1.z
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.x between t2.a and t2.b
             );
```